# Simplification of this trigonometric expression: $\tan(1°)×\tan(2°)×\tan(3°)×\tan(4°)×\cdots×\tan(87°)×\tan(88°)×\tan(89°)$

Tags: trigonometry, products

$$\tan(1°)×\tan(2°)×\tan(3°)×\tan(4°)×\cdots×\tan(87°)×\tan(88°)×\tan(89°)$$

What I tried is that I firstly changed all the $\tan$ to $\dfrac{\sin}{\cos}$ but I got stuck along the way..

Please help me guys

Comment: A far more interesting question would have been proving that $$\prod_{k=1}^n\tan\bigg(\frac k{2n+1}\cdot180^\circ\bigg)~=~\sqrt{2n+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$ \tan{(90-x)} = \frac{\sin{(90-x)}}{\cos{(90-x)}} = \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}} = \frac{1}{\tan{x}}. $$

Comment: Or directly $\tan(90^\circ-x)=\cot x=\dfrac1{\tan x}$

Comment: okay now I understand, so they will divide each out and I would be left with  sin(45°)/cos(45°) which is equal to  tan(45°)=1..


I appreciate Chappers